# Count of 1 value of a field not for other values in SQL query using CASE stmt

Tags: sql

Please help me resolve a problem where I want to get the sum/count of 1 values of a field, lets count of red balls in balls field. Right now I'm using case statement to get the count of red balls but case is giving the count of other balls as well. I'm looking for only 1record say count of red balls as 5

```
SELECT 
    b.ball_id, b.color,
    CASE WHEN b.color = 'Red' THEN COUNT(DISTINCT b.ball_id) END 
FROM
    ball_table b 
GROUP BY
    1, 2
```

expected result- 1 record only stating red colored balls are 5
what i'm getting is count of every colored ball say for red, its 5 and black is 9 and so on.

Comment: Put the case expression inside the COUNT instead.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help here.

Comment: _Column_, not field. `case` _expression_, not statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want one of the following two expressions:

```
SELECT b.ball_id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN b.color = 'Red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as num_red_rows,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN b.color = 'Red' THEN b.ball_id END)) as num_red_distinct_ids
FROM ball_table b 
GROUP BY b.ball_id;
```

I am guessing that `ball_id` is unique, so you want the expression for `num_red_rows`.

Answer (score 0):

use sum

```
SELECT b.ball_id,
b.color,
sum(CASE WHEN b.color='Red' then 1 END )
from ball_table b 
group by 1,2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your query.

```
SELECT     
  count(1) as ct
from ball_table
where color ='Red'
```

Comment: Hi @metal
its not working, result gives sum for other colored balls as well

Comment: updated, i think you only need to count balls = 'red'